# Execute SSRS report with multiple Subreports using SSIS package and Script task

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssis

I am not able to subscribe to the report at my work so I am trying to execute SSRS report (with multiple subreports )using SSIS script task to import the SSRS report and save it on a location. How to import and save an SSRS report with Subreports to .xls file(on different tabs)

I have read multiple posts on how to import and save the SSRS report on .xls files but they are all importing a report with just one tab. my report should be imported into multiple tabs.